# Taking a value from one matrix to another matrix based on rownames

Tags: r

That's the matrix which I have and I would like to add a new column to this matrix:

```
> dput(head(res))
structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(6L, 
20L), .Dimnames = list(c("AT1G01050_0", "AT1G01050_1", "AT1G01080_0", 
"AT1G01080_1", "AT1G01080_2", "AT1G01080_3"), c("10", "33.95", 
"58.66", "84.42", "110.21", "134.16", "164.69", "199.1", "234.35", 
"257.19", "361.84", "432.74", "506.34", "581.46", "651.71", "732.59", 
"817.56", "896.24", "971.77", "1038.91")))
```

The new column will be taken from the another matrix showed below:

```
> dput(head(data2))
structure(c("AT1G01050", "AT1G01080", "AT1G01090", "AT1G01320", 
"AT1G01470", "AT1G01800", " 24.5", " 32.6", " 47.2", "198.8", 
" 16.5", " 31.7"), .Dim = c(6L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("5", 
"9", "10", "35", "51", "87"), c("locus", "size2")))
```

As you see part of the name (before dash _) is the same. Based on that I would like to take the value from `size2` column and put it to the first matrix in a new column.

The output:

```
            10 33.95 58.66 84.42 110.21 134.16 164.69 199.1 234.35 257.19 361.84 432.74 506.34 581.46 651.71 732.59 817.56 896.24
AT1G01050_0  0     0     0     0      0      0      0     0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
AT1G01050_1  0     0     0     0      0      0      0     0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0
AT1G01080_0  0     0     0     1      0      0      0     0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
AT1G01080_1  0     0     0     0      0      0      1     0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
AT1G01080_2  0     0     0     0      0      0      0     0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
AT1G01080_3  0     0     0     0      0      0      0     0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0
            971.77 1038.91    size2
AT1G01050_0      0       0     24.5 
AT1G01050_1      0       0     24.5
AT1G01080_0      0       0     32.6
AT1G01080_1      0       0     32.6
AT1G01080_2      0       0     32.6
AT1G01080_3      0       0     32.6
```

Hope it won't be hard for some of you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step is to extract the roots from the row names of `res`:

```
(roots <- sapply(strsplit(rownames(res), "\\_"), "[", 1))
# [1] "AT1G01050" "AT1G01050" "AT1G01080" "AT1G01080" "AT1G01080" "AT1G01080"
```

Now you can use the `match` function to grab the proper sizes:

```
cbind(res, as.numeric(data2[match(roots, data2[,1]), 2]))
#             10 33.95 58.66 84.42 110.21 134.16 164.69 199.1 234.35 257.19 361.84 432.74 506.34 581.46
# AT1G01050_0  0     0     0     0      0      0      0     0      1      0      0      0      0      0
# AT1G01050_1  0     0     0     0      0      0      0     0      0      0      0      0      0      1
# AT1G01080_0  0     0     0     1      0      0      0     0      0      0      0      0      0      0
# AT1G01080_1  0     0     0     0      0      0      1     0      0      0      0      0      0      0
# AT1G01080_2  0     0     0     0      0      0      0     0      0      0      1      0      0      0
# AT1G01080_3  0     0     0     0      0      0      0     0      0      0      0      0      0      1
#             651.71 732.59 817.56 896.24 971.77 1038.91     
# AT1G01050_0      0      0      0      0      0       0 24.5
# AT1G01050_1      0      0      0      0      0       0 24.5
# AT1G01080_0      0      0      0      0      0       0 32.6
# AT1G01080_1      0      0      0      0      0       0 32.6
# AT1G01080_2      0      0      0      0      0       0 32.6
# AT1G01080_3      0      0      0      0      0       0 32.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood your question - the result is in the dataframe "d1"

```
d1 <- as.data.frame(res)
d2 <- as.data.frame(data2)
d1$locus <- gsub("_[0-9]*$", "", rownames(d1))
d3 <- merge(d1, d2, by="locus", all.x=T)
d1$size2 <- d3$size2
d1$locus <- NULL
```